# Transparent indexes for STL algorithms in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to simplify the work with indexes using STL algorithms. Specifically, I have an array of indexes to another container in order, so that the indexes are sorted with respect to the corresponding values in the other container.

I want to make work with data through indexes transparent for programmer. For example, I want to use [std::equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) to find a range in data using indexes without writing a predicate for this. The predicate with only two purposes: to store the `begin()` of data container and to provide code for indirect access.

I feel like I am reinventing the bicycle and STL should have something to solve this task, like it have predicates for [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), [std::negate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/negate), etc. I expect that somebody answers “Just use predicate [std::indirect_array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/indirect_array) and [std::indirect_binary_predicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirect_binary_predicate) in this way” or something alike. I would prefer the solution which would work with usual [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) containers.

**What I want to avoid**

In case I need to use STL algorithms on the indexed data, e.g. an array *data* with values and an array *indexes* with indexes, the algorithm refers to indexed data using both data container `begin()` and index.

I prefer to keep the indexes instead of pointers/iterators mainly because I want to reduce memory footprint. For Winx64 platform each int index in takes 4 bytes, while a pointer takes 8 bytes. Additionally, indexes usage simplifies arrays relocation, fit for work with structures of arrays (SoA) and some other operations.

The problem breaks down into two:

1. Representation of the indexes
2. Providing transparence for algorithms

I really can’t decouple these two, if somebody could, please provide the way to. The main reason is that when I would ask where and how to store the container `begin()` people will point out to the predicate with internal state which is exactly the second part of the question.

When I talk about the transparency, I mean that I want to use algorithms like [std::equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) to find ranges in values, not in indexes, but using the indexes as an entry point. Unfortunately, [std::equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) knows nothing of my intentions and will compare just indexes. Of course, I could handle this in comparator predicate, but this will force me to write it and, in every predicate, remember about the indirection.

Saving memory, I have to pay back, keeping somewhere or providing the `begin()` of the container.

So, most likely, I have to pass the `begin()` somewhere to algorithms and the best place for this is the predicate:

```cpp
struct Value {
    int data;
public:
    Value(int value) : data(value) {}
    operator int() const { return data; }

    bool operator < (const Value& rhs) const { return data < int(rhs); }
};

struct Index {
public:
    int index;
public:
    Index(int i) : index(i) {}
};

class Comparator {
    const std::vector<Value>& vec;
public:
    Comparator(const std::vector<Value>& vec) : vec(vec) {}

    bool operator () (const Value& lhs, const Index& rhs) const {
        return lhs < vec[rhs.index];
    }
    bool operator () (const Index& lhs, const Value& rhs) const {
        return vec[lhs.index] < rhs;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Value> v1 = { 0,30,20,40,10 };
    std::vector<Index> i1 = { 0,4,2,1,3 };

    Value value(30);

    auto range_pred = std::equal_range(i1.begin(), i1.end(), value, Comparator(v1));

    std::cout << std::endl << "With predicate:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*range_pred.first = " << v1[(*range_pred.first).index] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*range_pred.second= " << v1[(*range_pred.second).index] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "range_pred.second-range_pred.first " << std::distance(range_pred.first, range_pred.second) << std::endl;
}
```

The key problems are:

1. I have to provide the predicate every time, even for simple indirection, because it is the only place to store the reference to data vector.
2. If the user would forget to add predicate, the error messages will be killing.

**The key questions**

1. Can this be done simpler in modern C++?
2. Where is the best place to store the containers `begin()`? Is the predicate with state the best solution?
3. How to make this transparent, so that the developer using somewhere something like `std::indirect` (fictional) could forget about this forever and work with indexes like with values.

**With the goals**

1. Robustness: when a user could forget to provide the predicate and start getting crazy amount of STL errors, this doesn’t work; when some implicit conversions could ruin indirection, this doesn’t work, etc.
2. Readability and avoiding code duplication.
3. Memory footprint with an eye on performance.

I am sure that in modern C++/STL should be some ready solution.

I have dozens of indexes, dozens of predicates and many levels of indirection and want to simplify the code since in many places it becomes complex and at the same time, similar, although not identical. Most of it is indirection code.

Comment: Most containers do not even work with indices, but with iterators, or views/ranges.  So my first guess would be to rephrase your original problem into something that doesn't require indices.

Comment: you already lost me here "Each and every algorithm that is working with indexes" because I dont know any algorithm that is working with indices

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, thank you for the catch. I reworded to "Each and every algorithm while working with indexes" meaning "when I need to work with indexes using standard algorithms". Not sure what would be the best wording here. I have data vector, indexes vector and want to use with data through the indexes using standard STL algorithms transparently, like these indexes are absent and I work with the data directly. Could you please help me in rewording?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, as I stated in answer to "463..." , I rephrased the sentence. In case you can express it better, please feel free to provide the suggestion/hint or edit the question.

Comment: frankly, I think the question is too wordy. To make it easier to read, you could start with one concrete example of what you want to get done, and what code you'd like for that. Code examples speak more than thousand words. When reading the first code is already code that you do not want, but at that point it didnt actually understand what you do want

Comment: You start by trying to explain how you want to solve something, but what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Maybe you should start there.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, agree. First intermediate step has been removed for the sake of brevity. Does current wording work?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, I stated with this, as I understand it. I want to have work with data through indexes transparent for programmer. For example, I want to use std::equal_range to find a range in data using indexes without writing a predicate for this. The predicate with only two purposes: to store the begin() of data container and to provide code for indirect access.

Comment: what Pepijn says. Some very vague introduction aside the question starts with "What I want to avoid" before its clear what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I did my best. Be my guest to edit the question so that I could learn the best way to share the thoughts. At the moment this is the best wording I could provide. Is there any change to start getting some answers? :)

Comment: Do you just need a struct that contains a reference to a `Range` and a reference to a `std::vector<Index>` that provides some custom member functions?

Comment: You've removed your attempt, and now "forget to assign address" doesn't make sense in the current text.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, can you please share you hint in form of the answer so that I could understand the idea? I am not sure this will be generic enough and will simplify coding, but I am not sure, so the code would be better.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, thank you for catching this. Fixed.

Comment: Are you looking for [Boost.MultiIndex](https://cs.brown.edu/people/jwicks/boost/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial.html#:~:text=of%20the%20composition.-,Boost.,and%20often%20perform%20much%20better.)  and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html ?

Comment: With `ranges` algorithms, it seems you might "just" use appropriate "projection".

Comment: @RichardCritten, thank you, this is quite close topic, but as it is often in boost, the syntax is very difficult to read and understand and even I understand the problem inside out, it is hard for me to read the code. Anyway, I will read carefully and get back with the feedback. At the moment it seems to me that this syntax even more complicated than mine, although gives significant flexibility. The main concern for the moment, that it is not transparent, no every step I should remember about the indexes while I want to forget about them.

Comment: @Jarod42, can you please show this in code? I am not so experiences with ranges so far, so I can't see the way to use them in this way effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure this is what you expected, but normally indexing is achieved via projection, as @Jarod42 points out in the comments on the question. You can also use a custom view. Both approaches are shown below, with two closely-related variants shown for the custom view approach.

```
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Value {
    int data;
public:
    Value(int value) : data(value) {}
    operator int() const { return data; }

    bool operator < (const Value& rhs) const { return data < int(rhs); }
};

struct Index {
public:
    int index;
public:
    Index(int i) : index(i) {}
};

// Reusable generic for the standard approach using projections
// Added following @Jarod42's comment on this answer
template<std::ranges::random_access_range R>
auto create_index_projection(R&& range) { 
    return [&range](const Index& i){
        return std::ranges::begin(range)[i.index]; 
    }; 
}

// Reusable generic for the custom view approach
template<std::ranges::random_access_range R>
auto indexing(R&& range){
    return std::views::transform([&range](const Index& i) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::ranges::begin(range)[i.index];
    });
};

// Variant of the custom view approach, with the operands swapped
// Requires more work, but the order may be more "natural" and easier for composition
template<std::ranges::random_access_range I>
requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<I>, Index>
struct IndexObject {
    I&& indices;
    explicit IndexObject(I&& indices_):indices{std::forward<I>(indices_)}{}
};

template <typename I>
IndexObject<I> indexedby(I&& indices_){
    return IndexObject<I>{std::forward<I>(indices_)};
}

template <std::ranges::random_access_range R, std::ranges::random_access_range I>
auto operator | (R&& range, IndexObject<I> index_obj){
    return std::forward<I>(index_obj.indices) | indexing(std::forward<R>(range));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Value> v1 = { 0,30,20,40,10 };
    std::vector<Index> i1 = { 0,4,2,1,3 };

    Value value(30);

    //Standard approach: Using projection
    auto range_pred1 = std::ranges::equal_range(i1, value, {}, create_index_projection(v1));
    std::cout << "*range_pred.first = " << v1[(*range_pred1.begin()).index].data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*range_pred.second= " << v1[(*range_pred1.end()).index].data << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "range_pred.second-range_pred.first " << std::distance(range_pred1.begin(), range_pred1.end()) << std::endl;

    //Alternatve approach: Using custom view
    //May be the syntax you are looking for
    auto indexing_view = i1 | indexing(v1);

    auto range_pred2 = std::ranges::equal_range(indexing_view, value);
    std::cout << "*range_pred.first = " << (*range_pred2.begin()).data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*range_pred.second= " << (*range_pred2.end()).data << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "range_pred.second-range_pred.first " << std::distance(range_pred2.begin(), range_pred2.end()) << std::endl;

    //Variant of above, with more "natural" order in syntax
    auto indexing_view2 = v1 | indexedby(i1);

    auto range_pred3 = std::ranges::equal_range(indexing_view2, value);
    std::cout << "*range_pred.first = " << (*range_pred3.begin()).data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*range_pred.second= " << (*range_pred3.end()).data << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "range_pred.second-range_pred.first " << std::distance(range_pred3.begin(), range_pred3.end()) << std::endl;

    //Also works for rvalues provided that std::ranges::dangling is not returned by the algorithm
    bool binary_search_result1 = std::ranges::binary_search(std::vector<Value>{0,20,10}|indexedby(std::vector<Index>{0,2,1}), Value{10});
    bool binary_search_result2 = std::ranges::binary_search(std::vector<Value>{0,20,10}|indexedby(std::vector<Index>{0,2,1}), Value{15});
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::endl << "binary search for 10 " << binary_search_result1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "binary search for 15 " << binary_search_result2 << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/389Y99Mnz

The adaptors `indexing` and `indexedby` are aimed at code deduplication. You only need to define once, and then use either `index_range | indexing(indexed_range)` or `indexed_range | indexedby(index_range)` to obtain a view which you can almost use as a reordered range. Only one of the two variants need to be defined so you can choose whichever syntax that you find the most natural. This addresses the transparent requirement in your question. So let's say you have the following

```
std::string s="abc";
std::array<Index> indices[]{1,2,0};
auto sView = s | indexedby(indices);
//Or, equivalently
//auto sView = indices | indexing(s);
```

Note that now `indices` and `s` are of completely different types from above, but with the same definition of the adaptors `sView` can be used as a random access range containing "bca". It is random access because the underlying range `indices` is also so. That means for example `sView[2]=='a'` and `for(const auto c: sView){...}` does what you expect them to do (the latter does not really require a random access range though), which is good enough for most applications.

It is also composable. So for example if you have another level of indirection using a index vector `i2`, in addition to `i1` and `v1`, then you can just use the view `auto view = v1 | indexedby(i1) | indexedby(i2)` to access the elements transparently. Due to the restriction that overloaded `[]` must be a member function, a syntax like `v1[indexedby(i1)][indexedby(i2)]` is not possible.

---

Some more explanation about the definition of the `IndexObject` template: it is a thin wrapper (the extra cost in most C++ implementations being the memory of a single pointer) around a range of `Index` (e.g. `std::vector<Index>` in your example), and `indexedby` is actually just a more descriptive name for the `make` function of an `IndexObject`, it can just be called `makeIndexObject` just like `make_pair` is to `std::pair`.

Now, this thin wrapper around the original range of `Index` makes sure that the correct operator `|` is picked up for the syntax `v1 | indexedby(i1)`. It could have just been `v1 | i1`, by just changing the signature of `operator|`, but I have decided that that is too error-prone and does not convey the intention well, so I have chosen to make this extra wrapper.

So to summarize its purpose in a sentence: it is to wrap (capture) an existing range of `Index` to make the syntax `v1 | indexedby(i1)` possible. In the implementation of the corresponding operator `|` of many range adaptors, this is called a closure.

For the "how it works" part. Most of the information are already presented above, but I can rephrase it in a way corresponding to the natural program flow.

1. `indexedby` wraps (captures) a range of `Index`, which is an `IndexObject`.
2. The capture is combined with the range to inspect, which returns a random access `std::transform_view`.
3. The `std::transform_view` can then be used for accessing transparently.

Conceptually, it is not much different from `(Capture(i1))(v1) -> std::transform_view<decltype(i1), F>`.

---

At this point it may be tempting to get rid of the classes `Value` and `Index` entirely, since the original intent is preventing the misuse of an index vector as a value one. Doing so is in fact perfectly safe in terms of type safety. The reason is as follows.

For the `indexedby` adaptor, since a range cannot be converted to an `IndexObject` thanks to the `explicit` constructor, and an `IndexObject` is not a valid range itself, it is now crystal clear that for the values you have to use a real range and for indices you have to use an `IndexObject`. There's no way they can get mixed up in the type system. Similarly for the `indexing` adaptor, for the values you have to use a range adaptor and for the indices you have to use a real range, and of course the standard library doesn't allow implicit conversions between them.

The following snippet from [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cjG1Ph7an) clearly shows the type safety. For the definitions of the types involved in the demo, refer to the link to the demo itself. The demo is adapted from another demo provided by OP.

```
namespace TypeSafetyDemo{
    namespace Approach1{
        using Value = ValueObject<std::vector<int>&>;
        using Index = std::vector<int>;
        using F = void(*)(Value, Index);
        static_assert(std::invocable<F, Value, Index>);
        static_assert(!std::invocable<F, Value, Value>);
        static_assert(!std::invocable<F, Index, Value>);
        static_assert(!std::invocable<F, Index, Index>);
    }
    namespace Approach2{
        using Value = std::vector<int>;
        using Index = IndexObject<std::vector<int>&>;
        using F = void(*)(Value, Index);
        static_assert(std::invocable<F, Value, Index>);
        static_assert(!std::invocable<F, Value, Value>);
        static_assert(!std::invocable<F, Index, Value>);
        static_assert(!std::invocable<F, Index, Index>);
    }
}
```

An additional note is that since both adaptors capture the underlying range by reference, the usual warns about lifetime and reference members apply. Don't store an `indexedby(i1)` somewhere and use it after the lifetime of `i1` ends. For a similar reason, having a function signature of `f(std::vector<int>, IndexObject<std::vector<int>&&> index_obj)` is dangerous and not very useful, as the underlying `vector` will be moved to the `owning_view` in the first use of `index_obj`, and subsequent uses of `index_obj` will be invalid. I've also modified the template `IndexObject` to make `IndexObject<std::vector<int>>` ill-formed to prevent misuses similar to this.

If you really want to make `f(std::vector<int>, IndexObject<std::vector<int>&&>)` useful and safe, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7KPYhf9sr) provides an alternative. It only moves the underlying `vector` if both that `vector` and the `IndexObject` itself are rvalues.

---

About the suggestion from a now deleted comment: `R range` with `random_access_range R` does not guarantee `range[i.index]` is well-formed. In fact the concept does not say much about the member functions of `R` itself, only about its iterators. So in order to be general enough it is still necessary to use `std::ranges::begin(range)[i.index]`. Although all random access ranges in the standard library do provide `operator[]`.

Comment: Thank you. The code `return *(std::ranges::begin(range)+i.index);`, and especially its duplication in the indexing template and predicate for std::ranges::equal_range is what I want to avoid. I want to specify somewhere **indirection** and have this indirection done automatically for me like array[idx] does *(array+idx) automatically and like for std::vector the vec[idx] does *std::next(vec.begin(),idx) for me automatically in "invisible". Let me learn ranges and look for other answers before I mark this one as accepted. Thank you again for the example. I will try it.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I believe the `i1 | indexing(v1)` is quite reusable. You just need to define it once and use it anywhere.  I will make it clear in my edit.

Comment: I still learning the code, but one extra note, another thing I deadly want to avoid is to use in std::ranges::equal_range both v1 and i1. On one hand it allows the developer to use many indexes for the same data, on the other hand it is error-prone. It would be nice to build-in knowledge about v1 into i1 so that when in many places in code the i1 is used, the chance to use it to v2 (fictional, here) is low. Since many indexes could be used for one data, while many data collections very rarely used with one index (almost never).

Comment: It is not bulit into `i1`, it is built into the view `view = i1|indexing(v1)`, and then the call is just `equal_range(view, value)`.

Comment: Ops. You showed two different approaches. I had to read comments more careful. Now I see it. I really need some time to learn projections and views. It seems they worth it.

Comment: In the same way you create `indexing`, you might have `auto create_index_projection(auto&& r) { return [&r](auto&& i){ return return std::ranges::begin(v1)[i.index]; }; }`, and so `std::ranges::equal_range(i1, value, {}, create_index_projection(i1))`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good idea. Included in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solutions provided, it seems that now I got exactly a half of what I was looking for - separation of projection/view and comaparator. Now I don't need to put the `begin()` of the data array to comparator, it can be included into the projection or view. Now about the second half. It seems that the template `IndexObject` could be this part. How it and indexedby work? What is their purpose?

Comment: With all these changes if I go with views (first or second option), how safe it would be to get rid of my `Value` and `Index` classes which I created just as a defense against possible (that I or another developer have missed) implicit conversion which will under the hood consider `int` index as `int` value? I removed my classes and added `Index` template parameter so that I could use any type for indexes (please see the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q95c7KEcc)). Is it safe or implicit conversion can make it error-prone?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Addressed  in the answer, note that the template parameter `Index` is not really needed and I have removed it.

Comment: Two extra thoughts: (1) With my implementation [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q95c7KEcc) is there a chance to deduce the `Index` type somewhere in templates from the `std::ranges::random_access_range` parameter? Something like `R::value_type` or these types are totally unrelated in the template in terms of deduction? (2) With this jump to views I understand that I stuck with indexes sorting in the same view-style view, so I created another question [How to sort indexes...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506703/how-to-sort-indexes-to-data-through-views); could you, please, take a look?

Comment: I see they answered to both the questions above, but anyway, I will be thankful if you glance in case there are better solutions. Still hope to have something with views, not projections, although at the moment can't say for sure why in this particular case I prefer views; at the moment just for consistency and out of my lack of knowledge in projections/views area.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I have said that the Index parameter is not really needed and I don't understand why you added it back. The Index type is simply `std::ranges::range_value_t<I>` if `I` is the type of  the index range. The second one is a different question and honestly projection would be better suited for that job, but I will still try and see whether I can come up with anything.

Comment: Thank you so much, I messed up the `Index` parameter and my `Index` class in your answer, sorry for that. When I removed my 'Index' class, your implementation of `indexing` required something to replace the type `Index` there, see your code. So, I did my best to cascade it through all the templates, since I didn't know about `std::ranges::range_value_t<I>` or `std::ranges::range_difference_t<R>`; now I am reading the articles to catch up. Thank you and sorry for the mess.

Comment: @DamirTenishev That was the previous code. I already have a [new link](https://godbolt.org/z/cjG1Ph7an) in the updated part has already shown how to remove the `Index` template parameter without loss of generality. For your new question, I now do believe using a projection for sorting and then using the same projection to form a view as shown in the other answer for your transparent access is the best way. You don't have to restrict yourself to just one of the techniques as long as they solve your problem.

Comment: Of course. I just not very familiar with view and projections to see the difference and make correct choice decisions so far. The only thing I assumed that projections imply call-like structures which are hard to read for complex constructs and views imply pipeline-like structures, which are easier to read (not sure about debugging, yet). This was the only reason to vote for view at that moment. Now I learned both of them a little bit more (thanks to you) and hope to feel the difference better soon. Thank you.