# How to sort indexes to data through views?

Tags: c++, stl, std-ranges

In the code below the `values` vector contains data indexed by `indexes`. The template `indexing` allows transparent indexing for functions like `std::ranges::equal_range`, but I don't see the way to sort the array of indexes (not values themselves!) with ranges/projections/views approach.
What I can do is to create an "old-style" predicate `IndexedValuesComparator` for sorting and use it for `std::ranges::sort`.

Is there any chance to express the same with the views beauty without a predicate? Can this be done in the same way as it is done with the `indexing` template?

As I see the problem, I need to compare values, but swap indexes and this can't be done with views which provide only one entity. Is there a straightforward solution?

So, I just need what the `IndexedValuesComparator` does, but without it and in view-style.

It would be nice if the view could be used to get the sorted indexes on the fly (without storing the values), but this is optional.

**Motivation**

1. I need to have binding of many arrays with many indexes, sometimes with many levels of indirection, so I'd like to have short and safe way to express this.
2. I want to get rid of the comparator, since I need this "place" to put other comparators which will do more complex work and I don't want to mix them with the existing one.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Reusable generic for the custom view approach
template<typename Index, std::ranges::random_access_range R>
auto indexing(R&& range) {
    return std::views::transform([&range](const Index& i) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::ranges::begin(range)[i];
        });
};

template<typename Value> 
class IndexedValuesComparator {
    const std::vector<int>::const_iterator vec;
public: 
    IndexedValuesComparator(const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& vec) : vec(vec) {}

    bool operator() (const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return vec[lhs] < vec[rhs];
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = { 0,30,20,40,10 };
    std::vector<int> indexes = { 3,4,2,1,0 };

    auto indexing_view = indexes | indexing<int>(values);

    std::ranges::sort(indexes, IndexedValuesComparator<int>(values.begin()));

    int value_to_search(30);

    auto range_pred2 = std::ranges::equal_range(indexing_view, value_to_search);
    std::cout << "*range_pred.first = " << *(range_pred2.begin()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*range_pred.second= " << *(range_pred2.end()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "range_pred.second-range_pred.first " << std::distance(range_pred2.begin(), range_pred2.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qxa3PfzEn)

Comment: Are you saying that you want a view that will sort your data on the fly? Not storing the sorted data, like when you sort `indexes`, but something done as needed? Something like the view scans the range for the smallest element and produces that as the first element?

Comment: `std::ranges::sort(indexes, std::ranges::less{}, [&](int index){ return values[index]; });`?

Comment: @JaMiT, Sorting on fly would be good as well (I will be thankful for the hint for this!), but my current goal is just to *sort indexes* so that when values are accessed they are "sorted through indexes". I just need absolutely the same what is done with the `IndexedValuesComparator`, but without the comparator and done in view-style. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you so much for the option. The only thing (sorry, this wasn't in the initial question, I've updated later based on the question from JaMiT), I want to keep free the place for the comparator predicate, since I have more complex predicates that do real work and I don't want to mix the hierarchies of the predicates (although, maybe I just don't know how to do this effectively and transparently), so I will take this as homework. Anyway, thank you for the option.

Comment: It is very hard, if not impossible, to have the following syntax: `Magic obj{indexes,values}; std::ranges::sort(obj)` to get your task done. It seems that is the syntax you are looking for, but `std::ranges::sort` does not work that way. It compares the values in a range and sorts the same range, not some other range. You'll have to make a proxy object with a custom comparator to make it work, and the proxy object need to support the correct swap semantics. At this point it is too much work and also error-prone and doesn't really worth the hassle.

Comment: If you are worrying about multilevels of indirection, note that nothing stops you from forming `auto my_proj = make_index_proj(indexes1 | indexing(values))` and then `std::ranges::sort(indexes2, {}, my_proj)` from the accepted answer.

Comment: Just to prove how much hassle it would be to use a view to sort the index, I created a demo: https://godbolt.org/z/E5GTG97r8. It works but requires quite a few unintuitive hacks that I believe are standard-conforming but actually not entirely sure. Definitely this is not something  you want to put into production code.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, thank you so much for the demonstration and explanation. I agree that the code is really hurts. Especially comparison operators with hard-coded v1. I got the idea. And just to confirm that I did my homework, the `swap` template seems to be a trace of intermediate trials, so it is not necessary here.

Comment: The `swap` template is not necessary, but `swap(Proxy&&,Proxy&&)` need to be defined (not just declared) even though it is never actually called. This queer behavior is due to the hackish nature of the whole demo. `v1` can be changed to be not hard-coded by adding another reference member, but that would make things even more complex and the demo is already complex and hackish enough, so I didn't actually do it.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, this is quite interesting, since godbolt really shows the error if `swap` is missing, while MS Visual Studio 2022 with /std:c++latest compilation option compiles and runs this code without swap with no problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255986/discussion-between-weijun-zhou-and-damir-tenishev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a lambda that creates custom projections first

```
auto make_index_proj = []<std::ranges::random_access_range R>(R& range) {
  return [&range](std::ranges::range_difference_t<R> i) -> decltype(auto) {
    return std::ranges::begin(range)[i];
  };
};
```

(Note that we may need to accept lvalue range to avoid dangling. In addition, `random_access_iterator` only works with its `difference_type`, so there is no need to specify the index type, `range_difference_t` already does this for us)

Then uniformly pass the projection to `views::transform` and `ranges::sort`

```
std::vector<int> values = { 0,30,20,40,10 };
std::vector<int> indexes = { 3,4,2,1,0 };

auto my_proj = make_index_proj(values);

auto indexing_view = indexes | std::views::transform(my_proj);
std::ranges::sort(indexes, {}, my_proj);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Two questions: (1) Why in the original code in the question it was a view (or am I wrong here and the  `indexing_view' / 'indexing<int>(values)' is a projection here?) and in your code my_proj is a projection? How can I catch the difference in this case? (2) What is the best way to learn these projections/views for a person who is new for them (additionally to the standard and cppreference.com), something what would help to write these `make_index_proj` and 'indexing' functions?